# Can't put a useRef on the Ant Design drop-down menu button (React Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using a dropdown list from UI Framework Ant Design, I need to put useRef on it to control it, add or remove Visible={true} attribute. TypeScript gives me this error.

> Type '{ children: Element; ref: MutableRefObject;
> className: string; overlay: Element; trigger: "click"[]; }' cannot be
> assigned to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DropDownProps & { children?
> ReactNode; }'.   The 'ref' property does not exist for the type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & DropDownProps & { children? ReactNode; }'.

Below are two screenshots, Dropdown Button element and TS error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Who0V.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfhUM.png)

UPDATE**

My temporary solution looks like this, if I'm on the home page my drop down list is open, if I'm on other pages it opens after a click. But it would be better if through Ref, you could set or remove the attribute visible={true}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkSd1.png)

source code link https://github.com/grigoryanhrant/my-app/blob/master/src/components/Header/index.tsx

Answer (score 0):

React components do not have a `ref` prop by default, only base elements like `<div>` and `<span>` etc. do. In order for a React component to pass through a `ref` prop, you must use [`React.forwardRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

It looks like the `antd` "Dropdown" [component](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/dropdown/dropdown.tsx#L70) does not utilize `React.forwardRef()`, so you are screwed in this case. Of course, you could check their [contribution](https://ant.design/docs/react/contributing) guidelines and explore submitting an update to their codebase to implement this...

Comment: Yes, you're right, I created an empty project, without using TypeScript, tried forwardRef, the result is no error, but the current Ref is undefined.